# Double hyphens in lstlisting

Tags: latex

I am using lstlisting command in Latex. I want to use double hyphens "--help", but latex hyphens connects like in normal text (but it is source code) and I can't use "-{}-" for separation.

```
\begin{lstlisting} 
  $ oc <command> --help
\end{lstlisting}
```

Could you help me please? 
Thanks

Comment: This may belong on the TeX StackExchange. It's related to this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140216/how-to-avoid-double-dash-seem-as-a-continuous-line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seeing as you're using a terminal-like code display, consider using a `\ttfamily` as your `basicstyle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting} 
$ oc <command> --help
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```